# Why doesn't the compiler know the addresses of local variables at compile-time?

Tags: c++, c, variables, memory-management

What does the following statement mean?

> Local and dynamically allocated variables have addresses that are not known by the compiler when the source file is compiled

I used  to think that local variables are allocated addresses at compile time, but this address can change when it will go out of scope and then come in scope again during function calling.  But the above statement says **addresess of local variables are not known by the compiler.**   Then how are local variables allocated?   Why can global variables' addresses be  known at compile time??

Also, can you please provide a good link to read how local variables and other are allocated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In some sense, no address is known until the OS loads the program and sets up virtual memory mappings in the MMU.  The compiler knows the layout, that is the order in which things appear, but everything is measured from some base address.  For static storage duration, it's measured from the load address of the binary.  For automatic storage duration, it's measured from the stack pointer.  And dynamic storage has an address determined at run-time, but members are stored at an offset from the dynamic address.

Comment: @Ben: That's a completely separate issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The above quote is correct - the compiler typically doesn't know the address of local variables at compile-time.  That said, the compiler probably knows the offset from the base of the stack frame at which a local variable will be located, but depending on the depth of the call stack, that might translate into a different address at runtime.  As an example, consider this recursive code (which, by the way, is not by any means good code!):

```
int Factorial(int num) {
    int result;
    if (num == 0)
        result = 1;
    else
        result = num * Factorial(num - 1);

    return result;
}
```

Depending on the parameter `num`, this code might end up making several recursive calls, so there will be several copies of `result` in memory, each holding a different value.  Consequently, the compiler can't know where they all will go.  However, each instance of `result` will probably be offset the same amount from the base of the stack frame containing each `Factorial` invocation, though in theory the compiler might do other things like optimizing this code so that there is only one copy of `result`.

Typically, compilers allocate local variables by maintaining a model of the stack frame and tracking where the next free location in the stack frame is.  That way, local variables can be allocated relative to the start of the stack frame, and when the function is called that relative address can be used, in conjunction with the stack address, to look up the location of that variable in the particular stack frame.

Global variables, on the other hand, can have their addresses known at compile-time.  They differ from locals primarily in that there is always one copy of a global variable in a program.  Local variables might exist 0 or more times depending on how execution goes.  As a result of the fact that there is one unique copy of the global, the compiler can hardcode an address in for it.

As for further reading, if you'd like a fairly in-depth treatment of how a compiler can lay out variables, you may want to pick up a copy of **[Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools, Second Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)** by Aho, Lam, Sethi, and Ullman.  Although much of this book concerns other compiler construction techniques, a large section of the book is dedicated to implementing code generation and the optimizations that can be used to improve generated code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: *automatic*, not *local* (which may be `static`)

Comment: @BenVoigt- I agree.  I avoided using the term because most beginning programmers learn "local" and "global" as opposed to "automatic," "static," and "dynamic," as the former terms are more general and the latter typically apply only to C/C++.

Comment: @templatetypedef :i think i get you but could you please point out error in the answer of user966379 .He said that  "At compile time, source code is converted into machine language code so no address is known " .please give sweet answer as above .

Comment: @10001001058- The statement you're referring to is incorrect.  Machine code can absolutely have addresses hardcoded into it.

Comment: You might want to be more careful with "compile time" vs. "link time" when referring to when global addresses might be known.

Comment: @T.J.: Where you read the quote you added into ur question? Will you tell me that source?

Comment: @templatetypedef:  then who assigns address to a local variable? Linker/loader/assembler & when address is assigned at link time/runtime ?

Comment: @PravasiMeet Addresses of local variables are usually defined as relative offsets from the address of the stack pointer or frame pointer. The code to assign those offsets and manipulate the stack pointer is created by the compiler. It's only at runtime that all the information is available to determine which exact addresses are looked up.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the statement is not talking about runtime access to variables or scoping, but is trying to say something subtler.

The key here is that its "local and dynamically allocated" and "compile time".
I believe what the statement is saying is that those addresses can not be used as compile time constants. This is in contrast to the address of statically allocated variables, which can be used as compile time constants. One example of this is in templates:

```
template<int *>
class Klass
{
};

int x;

//OK as it uses address of a static variable;
Klass<&::x> x_klass;


int main()
{
   int y;
   Klass<&y> y_klass; //NOT OK since y is local.
}
```

It seems there are some additional constraints on templates that don't allow this to compile:

```
int main()
{
    static int y;
    Klass<&y> y_klass;
}
```

However other contexts that use compile time constants may be able to use `&y`.

And similarly I'd expect this to be invalid:

```
static int * p;

int main()
{
   p = new int();
   Klass<p> p_klass;
}
```

Since p's data is now dynamically allocated (even though p is static).

Comment: `Klass<&y>` in the second snippet is legal, most likely your compiler isn't implementing the Standard completely.  "A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:"..."a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or "... (section 14.3.2 `[temp.arg.nontype]`)  This is a significant change from C++03, which required external linkage.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was compiling in C++03 mode I think. I'm glad to see that some of the restrictions on templates have been reduced in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

1. Address of dynamic variables are not known for the expected reason,
   as they are allocated dynamically from memory pool.
2. Address of local variables are not known, because they reside on
   "stack" memory region. Stack winding-unwinding of a program may
   defer based on runtime conditions of the code flow.

For example:

```
void bar(); // forward declare
void foo ()
{
  int i;  // 'i' comes before 'j'
  bar();
}
void bar ()
{
  int j;  // 'j' comes before 'i'
  foo();
}
int main ()
{
  if(...)
    foo();
  else
    bar();
}
```

The `if` condition can be `true` or `false` and the result is known only at runtime. Based on that `int i` or `int j` would take place at appropriate offset on stack.

Comment: i think you answer that" local variable address is not known at compile time".but i have asked why address is not known by compiler itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's a nice question.

While executing the code, program is loaded into memory. Then the local variable gets the address. At compile time, source code is converted into machine language code so that it can be executed